# Find the generating set of $W=\{p \in \mathbb {P}_{3}(\mathbb{R}) \mid p(2)=0\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces

so i got stuck in this question. The purpose is to find a generating set for:

$$W=\{p \in \mathbb {P}_{3}(\mathbb{R}) \mid  p(2)=0\}$$

Where $ \mathbb {P}_{3}(\mathbb{R})$ is the vector space of the polynomials of degree three.
My idea was to write the polynomial in terms of a factor (x-2), so it would have the form:

$$p(x)=a_{o}+a_{1}(x-2)+a_{2}(x-2)^{2}+a_{3}(x-2)^{3}$$

So when x=2
$$p(2)= a_{o}=0$$

so the polynomal becomes

$$p(x)=a_{1}(x-2)+a_{2}(x-2)^{2}+a_{3}(x-2)^{3}$$

And the generating set would be

$$S=[(x-2),(x-2)^2,(x-2)^3]$$

But i'm not even a bit sure that it's right. I'd like to know what you guys have to say about it

Comment: Why do you doubt your solution? Observe that the three polynomials you have given are linearly independent over $\mathbb R,$ and they span $W,$ as you have shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is good. Here I provide an alternative solution for the sake of curiosity.

Express $p\in W$ as $p(x) = a + bx + cx^{2} + dx^{3}$. Based on the given assumption, one has that
\begin{align*}
p(2) = a + 2b + 4c + 8d = 0
\end{align*}

Consequently, it results that
\begin{align*}
p(x) & = -(2b + 4c + 8d) + bx + cx^{2} + dx^{3}\\\\
& = b(x - 2) + c(x^{2} - 4) + d(x^{3} - 8)
\end{align*}

Finally, we conclude that $W = \text{span}\{x-2,x^{2}-4,x^{3}-8\}$, and we are done.

Hopefully this helps.